# Use multiple colorbars in one figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, colorbar, color-mapping

I have a surface figure that visualizes three different matrices. I want to give them all different colorbars so I can identify the different matrices in the figure. For example, I want matrix 1 to be visualised in a range from yellow to orange, matrix 2 from light to dark green, and matrix 3 from light to dark blue. So in my figure I would need three different colorbars.

My result would be something like this

[image]

Comment: See [these utilities](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24371-colormap-and-colorbar-utilities-sep-2009) on the MathWorks File Exchange.